# Is there a way to compile raw hex code into a binary executable in C?

Tags: assembly, compilation, hex, nasm

I have plans for a certain program I want to build and for that I need a way to generate random assembly code and modify it.

I know how to use the `system()` function (C language) and I wanted to know if there is a way to create a file that contains only a raw hex code and then use `system()` to compile it in a compiler like NASM into a binary executable.

**Note: don't answer because i am about to make another page that answers to my needs... this is too general of a question for me. (sorry for the inconvenience...)**

Comment: `... a file that contains only a raw hex code and then use system() to compile it in a compiler ...` I think we don't compile raw hex, but we compile assembly code into hex

Comment: no... i think we compile assembly into hex and then into machine languge... your computer can't read hex...

Comment: Unless you are programming for some embedded system or using Z80 (or really old system) usually modern assemblers take an assembly file and assemble it directly into machine code. Or they assemble into an object file that is linked to a final excutable.

Comment: What is "raw hex code"? Do you want text file containing "12 34 AB FE ...", or do you mean binary file containing bytes? If binary bytes, what is wrong about [`fwrite`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm)?

Comment: i mean a txt file containing "1D35 C3D5 A29F..." i need 16 bit assembly commands

Comment: And I'm not sure what kind of tool there exists to convert text "1234ABFE" into binary 4 bytes (but I'm pretty sure GNU world has such tool available), but if you are already in C, and willing to use `system` to execute such tool, why just not write the conversion yourself, it's like 4-liner ... and write the binary yourself. (about "16 bit assembly commands" - that doesn't matter, the binary file contains bits grouped into bytes, i.e. if you will check the output file with hexa viewer, you will see `35 1D D5 C3 ...` bytes (or if you will switch the display to WORD, then you will see yours).

Comment: Thats my question... how do i make that conversion not only into 4 bytes but how can i make it binary...

Comment: 1234ABFE when stored as 4 byte constant in file already *is* binary, you have sort of wrong idea what the files are actually containing, and how it is stored in computer, and you are mixing up display-formatting (anything you wish, but for viewing binary files usually hexadecimal view is used for convenience, created by the viewer) with actual internal data format (only binary, and grouped by 8 bits into bytes usually, because memory is addressable by bytes).

Comment: The OP is saying the file is ASCII HEX in some format which is very relevant to the solution.  And wants it in binary, to execute.  Since this is a C program you are correct simply read the ASCII file and convert it to binary on the way in then run it, this turns into a self modifying code problem, but is quite doable.  Or even better the C program reads it, writes it out in a supported executable binary format then calls system.

Comment: strtoul will convert ASCII base 16, or god forbid you could use *scanf().  being base 16 it is somewhat trivial to convert, a simple look up table will do for each nibble, shift and or, shift and or.

Comment: nasm does not take ascii hex numbers and turn them into an executable binary, it CAN if that ascii is formatted properly as Ped7g pointed out dw 0x1234, dw 0xabcd.  The operating system which you have not bothered to tag/specify, only supports so many executable file formats, so to use system you have to present a file in that format, you have to convert it.  How is this HEX file been created, why not add a step in the build process to make it an executable binary instead of runtime?  If not you have to do it runtime.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question; just posting your answer here might be better than posting another Q&A pair.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use NASM for handling the correct binary executable meta data, and format cruft, and you want to produce only the main body of code, you can write to disk new ".asm" file with some header template, like:

```
           bits    64
global _start
_start:
```

And then add new lines to that:

```
    dw      0x1234
    dw      0xc3d5
    ...
```

Store such complete file under some "temp1234.asm" name, and then compile it with NASM into linux ELF 64b binary (you didn't specify in the question your target platform and CPU, so I'm using what is familiar and most common platform+OS today for example, for other platforms details may differ):

```
nasm -f elf64 temp1234.asm; ld -b elf64-x86-64 -o temp1234 temp1234.o
```

(using `system()` to execute this compilation step) and then you can execute the resulting `temp1234` binary with `system()` too.

---

If you want the resulting file to contain only your data, then you can use the C [`size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm) to write byte values directly into opened file (but don't forget to open it with binary file, like `FILE *f = fopen("name", "wb");`), the work-around with producing temporary ASM file above is worth the effort only when you actually want the assembler and linker to produce also the common meta-data of common executables, like ELF64, etc...

To prepare such binary data in C you can do for example:

```c
#include <cstdio>
typedef unsigned short word;
void foo() {
    word payload[3] = { 0x1D35, 0xC3D5, 0xA29F };
    FILE *f = fopen("temp.exe", "wb");
    fwrite(payload, 1, sizeof(payload), f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

(do NOT run resulting "exe" file created by this, it is not valid EXE binary to be executed, as it is missing header/meta data required by the DOS or Windows EXE variant files .. this is just example how to write binary data into file with C code).

---

And final note, if you will write pure x86-16 machine opcodes into file named "something.COM", it can be run directly under DOS, as the "COM" executable files format is "raw machine code loaded into single 64k segment of memory starting at offset 0x100", i.e. writing single byte `0xC3` into "test.com" will execute under DOS correctly (just returning back into DOS, because `0xC3` is `ret` instruction opcode).

But for most of the other target platforms you will have to produce much more complex executable files containing several meta-data in the properly structured header of the file, to make them valid executables. That's another reason why using assembler+linker is convenient when writing assembly code, not only the translation from text form into machine code, as the assembler+linker when targetting particular executable format will automatically produce all those header/meta data for you.

Comment: i think i found another more compact solution... tell if it will work cause im doing homework right now... what if print into a text file letters with the assembly opcodes as their ascii values and change the .txt into a .exe

Comment: @H3X3R that's not how ".exe" file works. Seriously, take a step back, and try to find some tutorial/explanation about what actually computer file on disk contains, then use some hexa viewer to view some ascii files (like C/ASM sources) vs produced EXE binary files, and keep in mind both of them are on the disk itself stored as bits (in binary way), it's viewer which is formatting those data into either hexa-view, or ASCII-text view. Then assembler like NASM will read the ASCII encoded binary ".asm" files, parse those ASCII bytes as strings, decode them, translate into machine code + write .obj

Answer (score 2):

```
_start:
    mov $1, %rax # write
    lea .foo, %rsi # text
    mov $6, %rdx # text size
    mov $1, %rdi # stdout
    syscall

    mov $60, %rax #exit
    syscall

 .foo: .ascii "Hello\n"
```

here's some assembly code (sorry, that AT&T, that's what I use, you asked for machincode anyway).

```
/tmp> as x.S -o x.o
/tmp> ld x.o -o x
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400078
/tmp> ./x
Hello
```

So that I know it works…

```
/tmp> objdump -d x | awk 'BEGIN{ printf " _start: .byte " } /  [0-9a-f]+:/ { i=2; while( $i ~ /^[0-9a-f]{2}$/ ){ printf "0x%s, ", $i; i++ } } END{ print "" }' > y.s
/tmp> cat y.s
 _start: .byte 0x48, 0xc7, 0xc0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x8d, 0x34, 0x25, 0xa0, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x48, 0xc7, 0xc2, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0xc7, 0xc7, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x05, 0x48, 0xc7, 0xc0, 0x3c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x05, 0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x0a,
```

That's how I extract machine codes and transform them into assembler readable syntax. And finally:

```
/tmp> as y.s -o y.o
y.s: Assembler messages:
y.s:1: Warning: zero assumed for missing expression
/tmp> ld y.o -o y
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400078
/tmp> ./y
Hello
```

Now do it in C. :)